# Required fields for properties within an array of objects schema definition

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have following schema definition. library is required. there can be many. so in that library object there are some other properties which is required. But though i use following code it is not validating. I mean book title is not required. title of the author is required.How can i fix this?

```
schema definition
    {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
      "type": "object",
      "required": ["library"],
      "properties": {

        "library": { 
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {"required":["title"],
              "type": "object",

              "properties": {
                "title": {
                  "type": "string"
                },

                "author": {
                  "type": "string"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }}}
```

json input

```
{"library":[]
}
```

expected json input

```
{"library":[{"title":"Max"}]
}
```

Comment: Please add examples of JSON objects that should validate and JSON objects that shouldn't. The question text is quite difficult to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want "json input" to fail.

If so, your problem is that you didn't describe a library with a book with missing title, Instead, your document says 'I am a library with no books'.

Failing JSON:

```
{"library":[{}]}
```

Alternately, if you want to probibit empty libraries: JSON Schema has a minLength property.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little difficult to understand, but I noticed that you are using the tuple form of the `items` keyword.  I'm sure that is not what you want.  Try the following schema and I think it will behave the way you expect.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["library"],
  "properties": {
    "library": { 
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "required": ["title"],
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "author": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```